# How to deal with Android ActionBar code throughout the code?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, code-reuse

I'm developing an app that has the same action bar for all `Activities`. The only thing that changes is the menu, which can be easily built dinamically.

At the moment, I have a `xml` file for each toolbar of each `Activity`, but there are plenty of code repetition thoughtout the code. How should I deal with it?

I've thought of making a single `xml` file and including it in the `Activities` layout. However, there are plenty of stuff that are made programatically, such as definition of the button, title and menu. These methods are located in the Activities `onCreate`. How is it done to reutilize this code?

Comment: move all staff with your toolbar into base class, for example BaseActivity and inherit all activities from it

Comment: @gio Yes but how am I going to configure the toobar for each case? I mean, shouldn't I `setContentView` before referencing views and setting/getting stuff from them?

Comment: sure, you can do that at onPostCreate method

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure If I understand you correctly, but maybe make class which extends after Activity (or if you use AppCompatActivity etc.) for example `class MyCustomActivity extends AppCompatActivity` implement there your actionbar, and then in every new Activity class where you need that ActionBar just extend MyCustomActivity. In this class you can ofcourse implement some public method to set menu in subclasses etc.

Comment: Yes but how am I going to configure the toobar for each case? I mean, shouldn't I `setContentView` before referencing views and setting/getting stuff from them?

Comment: As gio said, you can set it up by overriding onPostCreate